# How to add dashboard JSON in Grafana using ConfigMap - metadata.annotations: Too long

Tags: kubernetes, grafana

I have been setting up datasource and dashboard configurations in ConfigMap as following:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: datasource-configmap
data:
  datasource.yml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    datasources:
    - name: prometheus-service
      type: prometheus
      orgId: 1
      access: proxy
      url: http://prometheus:9090/
      basicAuth: false
---
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: dashboard-configmap
data:
  dashboard.yml: |-
    apiVersion: 1
    providers:
    - name: 'Prometheus'
      orgId: 1
      folder: ''
      type: file
      disableDeletion: false
      editable: true
      options:
        path: /etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards
  dashboardA.json: |-
    { // }
  dashboardB.json: |-
    { // }
...
...
  dashboardC.json: |-
    { // }
```

It works fine till there are certain numbers of lines in the above file, after which it kubectl complains with the following error:

```
The ConfigMap "grafana-configmap" is invalid: metadata.annotations: Too long: must have at most 262144 bytes
```

If I remove long configuration from dashboardC.json, then there are no issues.

How can I overcome this error because the goal is to setup all Grafana datasources and dashboards from a file and not setup on Grafana UI?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe splitting up the dashboard over multiple ConfigMaps could solve the issue. As long as a single definition isn't over `262144 bytes`. You could then presumable mount them by way of a [projected volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#projected)

Another option would be to mount the files at `/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards` by way of a job container or init container that contains the correct files. Build this container in some CICD setup and you can store your dashboards in a repo.

Maybe mounting an S3 bucket with the daskboards onto the filesystem is an option.

Personally; option 1 looks easiest but prone to failure over time. Option 3 looks overly complex, option 2 seems robust and fairly easy.

Comment: do you know if Grafana alerts can also be provisioned using ConfigMaps

Answer (score 0):

You can use `kubectl replace` instead of `kubectl apply` but if something goes wrong you will loose option to `rollback` (you still have an option to redeploy with old config).

If you are using spinnaker then you can add below annotation:

```
metadata:
  name: datasource-configmap
  annotations:
    strategy.spinnaker.io/replace: 'true'
```